# Restful Webservice Program

Tags: java, string, web-services, rest

I have Following Code how can i get return type as int in place of `String` :

```
@Path("name")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayParam(@QueryParam("no1")int no1,@QueryParam("no2")int no2)
{
    return (no1+no2)+" ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `no1+no2` as they are `int`:

```
@Path("name")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int sayParam(@QueryParam("no1")int no1,@QueryParam("no2")int no2)
{

    return no1+no2;
}
```

Comment: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Integer, and Java type int, and MIME media type text/plain was not found.  this exception came in console and HTTP 500 ERROR in explorer

Comment: Can you write about your project configuration, java version, libraries, are you using maven?

Comment: Why you need it as `Integer` ?
if so, return result as `String` and cast it to `Integer`.